# Symfony2/Doctrine can't find mapping file for custom Repository class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations, metadata

I love doctrine but I have some problems with mapping/annotations. At start I used mapping files. Then I converted in into annotations. Now I want o create custom repository class so I did as I read  here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes.

Unfortunately now I have an error:

```
No mapping file found named '\src\Vendor\ProductBundle\Resources\config\doctrine/SynchronizationSettingRepository.orm.yml' for class 'Vendor\ProductBundle\Entity\SynchronizationSettingRepository'.
```

Of course I don't have this file becouse I don't use mapping anymore.
I've added:

```
  * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Vendor\ProductBundle\Entity\SynchronizationSettingRepository")
```

to parent and regenerated entities. I have regenerate Entites by command php app/console doctrine:generate:entities VendorProductBundle and still nothing. Regural and doctrine meadata cache is clear.

Here is a YML which from I want to generate custom Repository one more time:

```
Vendor\ProductBundle\Entity\SynchronizationSetting:
    type: entity
    table: synchronization_setting
    repositoryClass: Vendor\SynchronizationSetting\Entity\SynchronizationSettingRepository
    indexes:
        id_product:
            columns:
                - id_product
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            unsigned: true
            comment: ''
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        open:
            type: string
            nullable: true
            length: 1
            fixed: true
            comment: ''
            default: '0'
        internet:
            type: string
            nullable: true
            length: 1
            fixed: true
            comment: ''
            default: '0'
    manyToOne:
        idProduct:
            targetEntity: Product
            cascade: {  }
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
                id_product:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

And here is a repository class:

```
<?php
    // src/Acme/StoreBundle/Entity/ProductRepository.php
    namespace Vendor\ProductBundle\Entity;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

    class SynchronizationSettingRepository extends EntityRepository
    {
        public function findAllOrderedByName()
        {
            return $this->getEntityManager()
                ->createQuery(
                    'SELECT p FROM AcmeStoreBundle:Product p ORDER BY p.name ASC'
                )
                ->getResult();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that adding `@ORM\Entity` did very little good as complete `.php` class file gets overwritten as soon as you run the `doctrine:generate:entities`. You need to add `repositotyClass` to your `YML` file instead.

If you switched to annotations for good, those `.yml` files (actually whole `doctrine` directory within `config`) are useless, apart as being intermediate files for generating annotaion-based entities.

Another thing: It seams that Doctrine thinks you have a entity with name ending with "Repository".

Can you show us the content of `YML` file? If you don't have it (as you said), generating entities will not be possible. You can always generate annotaion-based entities directly (no need for `YML` intermediates)

Comment: I've updated my post with YML file and Repository class contents. Strange. I created YML files from database using generator. Then created entities with this YML's and... still the same error.

Comment: You can't use mapping and annotation within the same bundle.  Has to be one or the other and if you want to use annotations then you need to make the config/doctrine directory go away.  And as @jperovic has pointed out.  Having a xxxRepository.orm.yml file makes no sense at all.  Only entities have mappings or annotations.